# How can we persist changes in a docker container? I am using a python program to scrape and save data in a sqlite3 db file

Tags: python, docker, sqlite, web-scraping

```
personal=df.values.tolist()
conn=sqlite3.connect("data.db",detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES) 
cursor=conn.cursor()
for item in personal:
    cursor.execute('insert or replace into Final values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', item)
conn.commit()
```

There is no mention of sqlite in the dockerfile, what should I do to save changes in the data.db file?

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ADD linkedin_scrape.py .

COPY data.db ./data.db


# set display port to avoid crash
EXPOSE 8080

CMD python linkedin_scrape.py --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --timeout 90
```

This is my dockerfile.Can you please guide me step by step, thanks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to determine in which directory in the container the (Python) process is running.

Often you can discern this from the `WORKDIR` directory used in the `Dockerfile`.

Then -- assuming that `data.db` is created in that directory -- you can use Docker's volume mounting to mount a host file into the container at the same location.

For example:

```sh
HOST=${PWD}
CONT=${WORKDIR}

docker run --volume=${HOST}/data.db:/${CONT}/data.db ... your-image
```

Where `HOST` points to the directory on the host and `CONT` points to the directory (probably the same directory as used by `WORKDIR`) on the container.

> **NOTE** If, after running the container, the host's (!) `data.db` is a directory rather than a file, then you've incorrectly determined the file's location in the container. By default, Docker volume mounts directories not files.

> **NOTE** Another way to identify the container file's location is to `docker exec` into the running container and locate the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what I want to know is that will this method update the data.db file inside the container and everytime I run the code, db will be updated? Data.db file is already in the image, I copied it there. And I havent made workdir, sorry for asking silly questions.

Comment: Not a "silly question". If the file already exists in a running container, you can (probably) copy it from the container to the host using `docker cp`. Once you have a local copy, you can subsequently mount it into the container so that its contents persist across `docker run`'s.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am trying to locate the file in the container, thanks again